# Java trying to set Frame resizable(false) on the fly

Tags: java, swing, componentlistener

I'm working on an old java awt application and I try to change the resizable property of the main Frame by the code "on the fly" when needed.
The problem is that I've got a ComponentListener linked to this Frame and when I disable then enable my Frame resizing, I loose the ComponentListener.

Here the piece of code I'm using to do that :

> Frame constructor:

```java
compListener = new ComponentListener() {
      public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
           ScreenManager.windowResized(arg0.getComponent().getSize());
      }
            
      public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            
      public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
};

addComponentListener(compListener);
```

> My method to enable/disable the resizable status of my frame:

```java
public void setResizableStatus(boolean isResizable) {
     this.removeComponentListener(compListener);
     this.setResizable(isResizable);
     if (isResizable)
     {
         this.addComponentListener(compListener);
     }        
     this.revalidate();
     this.repaint();
}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: I dont get your question: your code removes the listener ALWAYS, but only when that parameter is true, the listener is added again. Why that if? And what do you expect to happen if the parameter is false?!

Comment: At the beginning my setResizableStatus method had just one line : this.setResizable(isResizable);

Comment: Note that you didnt answer my question. You are showing this code, and I am explaining to you, that depending on how this method is invoked, it **obviously** "forgets" that listener. Again: what do you expect to happen when this method is invoked with `false`?!

Comment: Sorry. When this method is invoked I just expect my Frame is no more resizable

Comment: Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. So all you need is a JFrame with a JCheckBox. The ActionListener for the checkbox will set the resize state of the frame. Simplify the problem while debugging the code. If it works, then you figure out what the difference is between this and your real app. If it doesn't work, then you have simple, complete code to post.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the code shown here does:

- **always** remove the listener
- **not** always re-add the listener

Thus the solution should be to:

```
if (isResizable)
{
    this.addComponentListener(compListener);
}
```

remove that if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code like this :

```
public void setResizableStatus(boolean isResizable)
{
    this.removeComponentListener(compListener);
    this.setResizable(isResizable);

    this.addComponentListener(compListener);
    
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}
```

But the result is the same, I loose my ComponentListener. I really don't know why.

Comment: How do you know that you loose it? What was your experiment?